# Inputting data to a dictionary(perhaps from a file) with nested lists as the values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input

All, I need to find an effective way to input my data into my script to end up with a dictionary that looks like so:

```
CSSes_2_add = {
    'Test CSS 1': ['Test CSS 1',['Staging','On Cluster','Test9','Test8', 'Test7', 'Test6', 'Test5',]],
    'Test CSS 2': ['Test CSS 2',['On Cluster','Staging','Test1','Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5']],
    'Auto Registered Devices': ['For Auto Registered Device Templates' ,['Block Toll Fraud']]
}
```

Please note that the number of elements of: `CSSes_2_add[x][1] will be different for each key of the dictionary. Instead of hardcoding my dictionary into my script, I'd like to know of a more efficient way to input my data. Please help

P.S.
If the suggestion is CSV, how do I handle the varying number of elements of the nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `DictReader`:

I have a CSV input file named "addCss.csv" with the following contents:

```
CssName,CssDesc,Partition1,Partition2,Partition3,Partition4,Partition5,Partition6,Partition7,Partition8,Partition9,Partition10,Partition11,Partition12,Partition13,Partition14,Partition15
CSS1,Description for CSS1,On Net,Staging,,,,,,,,,,,,,
CSS2,Description for CSS2, Test1, Test3, Test5,,,,,,,,,,,,
CSS3,Description for CSS3, Partition1, Test9, Test6,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I then loop through the file and add the data to my dictionary as follows:

```
with open('addCss.csv', newline='') as css_csv_file:
  css_csv_reader = csv.DictReader(css_csv_file)
  CSSes_2_add = {}

  for css_row in css_csv_reader:
      css_input_outer_list = []
      css_input_nested_list = []
      css_input_outer_list.append(css_row['CssDesc'])
      CSSes_2_add[css_row['CssName']] = css_input_outer_list
      for N in range(1,15):
          n = str(N)
          if css_row['Partition'+n] != '':
              css_input_nested_list.append(css_row['Partition'+n])
      css_input_outer_list.append(css_input_nested_list)
  print(CSSes_2_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using the data you have listed above an easy way of doing what you want is to loop through all the keys and data.

```
keys = ['Test CSS 1', 'Test CSS 2', 'Auto Registered Devices']
data_keys = ['Test CSS 1','Test CSS 2','For Auto Registered Device Templates']
d1 = ['Staging','On Cluster','Test9','Test8', 'Test7', 'Test6', 'Test5']
d2 = ['On Cluster','Staging','Test1','Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5']
d3 = ['Block Toll Fraud']
allData = [d1,d2,d3]
d = {}

for key, data_key in zip(keys, data_keys):
    d[key] = [data_key]

for key, data in zip(list(d.keys()), allData):
    d[key].append(data)
```

This will get you what you asked for, but if you are planning on accessing data from this dictionary it might get a little messy having to run through the nested list indexes.